# JPA CriteriaQuery class's "from" method does not accept entity class. Throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to pass in a entity class into JPA CriteriaQuery class to make a MySQL search operation. But at run time i get an error saying

> "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class

`com.flowManagementSystem.entity.Users` `com.flowManagementSystem.entity.User`s is my entity class

Class has `javax.persistence.Entity` annotation and the table name. Also, class is mapped in `hibernate.cfg.xml` file

```
//hibernate config> 
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    ...
        <mapping class="com.flowManagementSystem.entity.Users" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

//Entity class> 
package com.flowManagementSystem.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


import javax.persistence.Column;

import java.util.Date;



@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name = "us_prime")
private int usPrima;

@Column(name = "us_id")
private String usId;
```

I am expecting it to connect to MySQL DB and pull some data

P[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F45s.png)

Comment: This is the error message

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class com.flowManagementSystem.entity.Users
 at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.entity(MetamodelImpl.java:536)
 at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.QueryStructure.from(QueryStructure.java:126)
 at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl.from(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:153)
 at com.flowManagementSystem.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.getLoginUser(UserDaoImpl.java:38)
 at com.flowManagementSystem.services.UserLoginService.getUser(UserLoginService.java:14)

Comment: JPA does not use some Hibernate specific relic file. It uses persistence.xml and orm.xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `<class>com.flowManagementSystem.entity.Users</class>` entry into `persistence.xml`.

Persistence units are defined in a persistence.xml file, which has to be located in the META-INF directory in the classpath. One persistence.xml file can include definitions for one or more persistence units. The portable way to instantiate an EntityManagerFactory in JPA (as explained in the JPA Overview section) requires a persistence unit. More details [here](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/persistence-unit).

Comment: the persistence.xml should be inside the /src/main/resources ? or in a sub-directory of it?

Comment: It should be placed under directory META-INF under root of classpath

Comment: Still no luck put it into /src/main/resources/META-INF
this is what my persistence.xml looks like


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.2"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <!-- Define persistence unit -->
    <persistence-unit name="my-persistence-unit">
     <class>com.flowManagementSystem.entity.Users</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

Comment: if possible add snap of your project structure

Comment: I added a pic to the main question

Comment: Do you see persistance.xml file under WEB-INF/classes/META-INF directory after build ?

Comment: yes it is showing.. do you know of a simple program solution that can show me the basic of setting up the DB connectivity. I can then develop on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

you can also make a SessionFactory from Code. it work for me perfectly fine.

```
public static SessionFactory buildSessionFactoryFromAnnotatedClasses( List<Class> annotatedClassNames,Configuration config) {
    StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry =
        new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
    MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry);
    annotatedClassNames.forEach(sources::addAnnotatedClass);
    Metadata metaData = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();
    return metaData.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
  }
```

In your main method

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
Configuration config=  new Configuration()
        .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url","jdbc:mysql://host:port/database")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "userName")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "password");
        // set all other properties which you want to set
       SessionFactory factory=buildSessionFactoryFromAnnotatedClasses(Arrays.AsList(Users.class),config);
 }
```

Comment: I am making a REST API so my main class is slightly different to your, can i still add the config you said?

main class [package com.flowManagementSystem.main;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.flowManagementSystem"})
public class FlowManagementSystemApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(FlowManagementSystemApplication.class, args);
 }
}
]

Comment: @Java-Noob-Dev yes you can put these two static functions in some utility class and you only have to load the configuration from from hibernate.cfg.xml or you can create in the code.
whenever you want that sessionFactory just call the function.